# Stopping a thread that runs an action periodically

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, thread-safety

I have a class that (among others) needs to run an action at fixed intervals of time. So I created a thread for this:

```
struct Logger
{
   std::chrono::milliseconds flush_interval_;
   std::thread flush_thread_;

   Logger(...) : flush_thread_{&Logger::flush_thread_function, this}, ... {}

   auto flush_cb() -> void; // this is the action that need to be ran periodically

   auto flush_thread_function() -> void
   {
       while (true)
       {
           std::this_thread::sleep_for(flush_interval_);
           flush_cb();
       }
   }
};
```

The problem with this is of course stopping this thread when the object is destroyed. I came with a solution involving `condition_variable` that seems to work, but since I don't have much experience with multi-threading and I am just getting my head around `condition_variable` I want to make sure the solution is OK.

This is the part of the class that deals only with this:

```
class Logger
{
private:
    std::chrono::milliseconds flush_interval_;

    bool flush_stop_ = false;
    std::condition_variable flush_stop_cv_{};
    std::mutex flush_stop_mutex_{};

    std::thread flush_thread_;

public:

    Logger(std::chrono::milliseconds flush_interval = 1s)
        : flush_interval_{flush_interval},
          flush_thread_{&Logger::flush_thread_function, this}
    {
    }

    ~Logger()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_guard{flush_stop_mutex_};
            flush_stop_ = true;
        }

        flush_stop_cv_.notify_all();
        flush_thread_.join();
    }
private:

    auto flush_cb() -> void;

    auto flush_thread_function() -> void
    {
        auto prev_flush = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        while (true)
        {
            auto next_flush = prev_flush + flush_interval_;

            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{flush_stop_mutex_};
            auto stop_reason = flush_stop_cv_.wait_until(lock, next_flush);

            if (stop_reason == std::cv_status::timeout)
            {
                flush_cb();
                prev_flush = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            }
            else if (flush_stop_)
            {
                // could call flush_cb() one last time here,
                // but I have another mechanism that deals with unflushed log entries
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // this is a spurious wakeup
                // nothing to do here
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I am interested if my logic is solid and if the implementation is (thread-) safe. I chose `wait_until` and this overload in particular because the condition won't tell me if it was a timeout or a spurious wakeup. Another part that I am not entirely sure it's ok is the locking/unlocking of `flush_stop_mutex_` in `~Logger()` and the use of `lock` in `flush_thread_function`. As I understand after waking `flush_stop_mutex_` is locked protecting `flush_stop_` until the end of the current iteration of `while`, so I reason it is correct.

Comment: dealing with exceptions in `~Logger()` is another matter. `flush_stop_mutex_.lock()` and `flush_thread_.join()` can throw and I don't know how to deal with those inside the destructor. Don't know if that would be on topic here, so I leave it just as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is *almost* correct. Here's your code stripped down:

```
    while (true)
    {
        auto next_flush = prev_flush + flush_interval_;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{flush_stop_mutex_};
        auto stop_reason = flush_stop_cv_.wait_until(lock, next_flush);

        // stopping logic omitted
    }
```

Notice that the `unique_lock` is destroyed at the `}`, and so the mutex is *not locked* for a little while, until the next time you loop around and hit the `std::unique_lock` line. If another thread destroys the `Logger` during this period, it'll notify `flush_stop_cv_` but you won't be listening and so you'll miss the notification... and that was your *one chance* to hear it, so now you'll never stop and your program is frozen.

Solution: If you're waiting for a notification that you *absolutely must hear*, then *absolutely do not stop listening*. Don't drop that lock!

```
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{flush_stop_mutex_};
    while (true)
    {
        auto next_flush = prev_flush + flush_interval_;
        auto stop_reason = flush_stop_cv_.wait_until(lock, next_flush);

        // stopping logic omitted
    }
```

Or if you're really worried about holding the mutex for some reason, then check again after taking the lock but before going to sleep:

```
    while (true)
    {
        auto next_flush = prev_flush + flush_interval_;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{flush_stop_mutex_};
        if (flush_stop_) break;  // IMPORTANT LINE ADDED
        auto stop_reason = flush_stop_cv_.wait_until(lock, next_flush);

        // stopping logic omitted
    }
```

Otherwise, looks good to me.

---

`condition_variable::wait_until` is a fairly obscure function, IMO. Here you're assuming that it is implemented correctly and efficiently. I'm not *sure* that it always is, but I have no evidence to the contrary. The only immediately obvious way to get rid of `wait_until` is almost certainly worse: You could set another thread to notify the condition variable every `flush_interval_` seconds, and detect spurious wakeups by computing `std::chrono::system_clock::now() - prev_flush_`, instead of by looking for `std::cv_status::timeout`.